# Bash loop is not working when word contains space

Tags: bash

I am using `JQ` module the parse some of the data and then running the final loop over it to parse few more data.

```
cluster_list=`databricks --profile hq_dev clusters list --output JSON   | jq  'select(.clusters != null)  | .clusters[] |  [.cluster_name,.autotermination_minutes,.state,.cluster_id] | @csv' | grep -v "job-"`
    for cluster in ${cluster_list[@]}
    do
        cluster_id=`echo $cluster| cut -d "," -f 4 | sed 's/\"//g' | sed 's/\\\//g'`
        cluster_name=`echo "${cluster}"| cut -d "," -f 1| sed 's/\"//g' | sed 's/\\\//g'`
        echo $cluster_name
    done
```

**cluster_list** contains following value.

```
 "\"Test Space Cluster\",15,\"TERMINATED\",\"ddd-dese23-can858\""
"\"GatewayCluster\",15,\"TERMINATED\",\"ddd-ddsd-ddsds\""
"\"delete_later\",15,\"TERMINATED\",\"1120-195800-93839\""
"\"GatewayCluster_old\",15,\"TERMINATED\",\"0108-2y7272-393893\""
```

**it prints following.**

```
Test
Space
Cluster
GatewayCluster
delete_later
GatewayCluster_old
```

**Desired output**
it shouldn't break to newline if there is a space, I am doing few more action by the name I am getting here.

```
Test Space Cluster
GatewayCluster
delete_later
GatewayCluster_old
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Try quotes: `for cluster in "${cluster_list[@]}"`

Comment: You can (probably) dump the quotes with `jq -r` rather than using sed.

Comment: Put your script into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and follow all the advice, especially SC2068

Comment: To iterate over csv use csv aware tools... but ultimately I would toss `@csv` altogether and concentrate on how to import json values in bash properly. I believe you could have that desired output only in `jq`, what does `grep -v "job-"` exactly do? The `${cluster_list[@]}` will not help and quoting it will expand to just one big element - `cluster_list` is not an bash array, it is a normal variables with 4 lines. And please don't use \` backticks, use `$(...)` instead.

Comment: What does the original JSON look like? You can probably do this *entirely* in `jq`.

Comment: @chepner, I think you're right. It depends of the real inner content of the loop (just an echo or something more complex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script seems a bit overly complex to achieve your goal. Better use `read` to store each value in a separate variable, and set a comma for the input field separator `IFS`:

```
databricks --profile hq_dev clusters list --output JSON   |
    jq  'select(.clusters != null)  | .clusters[] |
         [.cluster_name,.autotermination_minutes,.state,.cluster_id] | @csv' |
    grep -v "job-" |
    sed 's/\\\?"//g' |
    while IFS=, read name autotermination_minutes state id ; do
      echo $name
    done
```

---

Note: I didn't touch your `jq` command. The `sed` line I put aims to remove quotes, protected or not. You can tune `jq` to remove these quotes with `-r`, as said in the man page:

> **INVOKING JQ**
>
> [...]
>
> - `--raw-output / -r:`:
>
>   With  this  option, if the filter´s result is a string then it will be **written directly** to standard output **rather than** being  **formatted** as a JSON string with **quotes**. This can be useful for making jq filters talk to non-JSON-based systems.